# How to disable the task pane in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

How to disable the annoying task pane from appearing everytime I run Impress from Libreoffice. I do not want to keep going everytime to untick it in the View tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug (see here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35973).  It looks like there was a fix added to the code recently, I tested libreoffice 4.0 (pre-release) and it seems to be working as you would expect there.

To get version 4 (there are possibly other ways)
start here: http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?nodetect
pick 32bit or 64bit deb (for ubuntu)
pick your language
pick version 4.0.0
download & extract
(at this point I'd use synaptic to uninstall all libreoffice things you have, but strictly speaking I guess this isn't necessary)
in the DEBS dir, run "sudo dpkg --install *.deb"
and it will install to /opt/libreoffice4.0 or somesuch.